# Problem with run code in specific time Java

Tags: java, android-studio

In my broadcast receiver class,
I need to mute then later unmute the phone.
The first mute works fine,
but the unmute does not work

```java
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context,"mute started for 50 sec ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    MainActivity.audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

    final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        }
    }, 50, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Q: Have you confirmed that your anonymous "run()" routine is ever invoked?

Comment: Do you know if the `run` method is being executed?

Comment: Yes, in the first mute  phone go silent for 50 sec and then unmute. in the second mute, it doesn't work

Comment: Are you letting your reference to the `ScheduledExecutorService` go out of scope? (A) You need that reference to eventually shutdown the executor gracefully, otherwise its backing pool of threads may continue running indefinitely, like a zombie ‍♂️. (B) The executor may become a candidate for garbage collection. Perhaps that is causing your problem, but I’m not sure.

Comment: I shutdown the executor and it worked thank you so much